# Extending the LineSeries in the WPF Toolkit charting to provide data tags

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, data-visualization, wpftoolkit

I copied an implementation that I found which provides data tags on a line chart from the WPF Toolkit DataVisualization and changed it around a little. It displays the value of a plot next to the data point. The chart redraws itself with different data every so often and the data tags are not removed when this happens.

I over-rode the `RemoveDataPoint` method from the base class to attempt to remove the `TextBlock` from the `Canvas` but this is throwing an `InvalidOperationException` (The enumerator is not valid because the collection changed). I understand why the exception occurs but how can I remove the `TextBlocks` from the `Canvas` when the corresponding `DataPoint` is removed?  This is what I have so far:

```
public class DataTagLineSeries : LineSeries
{
    private Canvas _labelsCanvas;

    private readonly Dictionary<DataPoint, TextBlock> _currentLabels = new Dictionary<DataPoint, TextBlock>();

    public bool DisplayLabels { get; set; }
    public string LabelBindingPath { get; set; }
    public Style LabelStyle { get; set; }
    public Point LabelOffset { get; set; }

    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        _labelsCanvas = (Canvas)GetTemplateChild("PlotArea");

        Clip = null;
    }

    protected override void UpdateDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
    {
        base.UpdateDataPoint(dataPoint);

        if (DisplayLabels && dataPoint.Visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (Action)(() => CreateLabel(dataPoint)));
    }

    protected override void RemoveDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint)
    {
        base.RemoveDataPoint(dataPoint);

        if (_currentLabels.ContainsKey(dataPoint))
        {
            _labelsCanvas.Children.Remove(_currentLabels[dataPoint]);
            _currentLabels.Remove(dataPoint);
        }
    }

    private void CreateLabel(DataPoint dataPoint)
    {
        TextBlock label;

        if (_currentLabels.ContainsKey(dataPoint))
        {
            label = _currentLabels[dataPoint];
        }
        else
        {
            label = new TextBlock();

            _labelsCanvas.Children.Add(label);

            _currentLabels.Add(dataPoint, label);

            label.Style = LabelStyle;

            var binding = LabelBindingPath != null
                                    ? new Binding(LabelBindingPath) { Source = dataPoint.DataContext }
                                    : new Binding("DependentValue") { Source = dataPoint };

            BindingOperations.SetBinding(label, TextBlock.TextProperty, binding);
        }

        var coordinateY = Canvas.GetTop(dataPoint) + LabelOffset.Y;
        var coordinateX = Canvas.GetLeft(dataPoint) + LabelOffset.X;

        Canvas.SetTop(label, coordinateY);
        Canvas.SetLeft(label, coordinateX);
    }
}
```